# How does a RADAR detect multiple targets?

Tags: signal-processing

I get detections in the form of a point(range index,doppler index) .If I have multiple targets ,i will get multiple points for those many targets.So how can the RADAR distinguish which point corresponds to which target?

Comment: This is not a programming question at all. Also, there are many types and architectures of radars, so this is both too broad and unclear, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is an idea of something called **"Range Resolution".**

The ability of a radar system to distinguish between two or more targets on the same bearing but at different ranges. The degree of range resolution depends on the width of the transmitted pulse, the types and sizes of targets, and the efficiency of the receiver and indicator.

**Pulse width** is the primary factor in range resolution. A well-designed radar system, with all other factors at maximum efficiency, should be able to distinguish targets separated by one-half the pulse width time τ. Therefore, the theoretical range resolution cell of a radar system can be calculated from the following equation: d >= ct/2, where c=speed of light, and t=time.

You can read more about it here: http://www.radartutorial.eu/01.basics/Range%20Resolution.en.html

Comment: What I mean is - The RADAR transceiver receives multiple reflections from multiple targets. How does it distinguish between the signals ? or how does it map a specific signal to a specific target?

Comment: @Hp179 Your two questions are in different areas. How does it distinguish? as I said using the idea of range resolution. How does it map to a specific target? you might be asking about localization - using distance and AoA (angle of arrival)